# asiHttpRequest under iOS5

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, asihttprequest

I am succesfuly using AsiHttpRequest library to make url connections in my apps. However, I upgrade to iOS5 and Reachability.m file is reporting some errors (4) on following functions:

```
static void ReachabilityCallback(SCNetworkReachabilityRef target, SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags, void* info) {

    #pragma unused (target, flags)
    NSCAssert(info, @"info was NULL in ReachabilityCallback");
    NSCAssert([(NSObject*) info isKindOfClass: [Reachability class]], @"info was the wrong class in ReachabilityCallback");


    // Post a notification to notify the client that the network reachability changed.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: kReachabilityChangedNotification object: (Reachability *) info];


} // ReachabilityCallback()


- (BOOL) startNotifier {

    SCNetworkReachabilityContext    context = {0, self, NULL, NULL, NULL};

    if(SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback(reachabilityRef, ReachabilityCallback, &context)) {

        if(SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop(reachabilityRef, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode)) {

            return YES;

        }

    }

    return NO;

} // startNotifier
```

1sr error: in NSCAssert line, "Cast of C pointer type 'void' to Objective-C pointer type NSObject requires a bridged cast". Why happens and how to solve it?

ANSWER: you can disable ARC for each file. Go to build settings of your project and set the -fno-objc-arc flag on all the ASIHTTPRequest files (double click to edit text). Then you must remove ASIAuthenticationDialog and any references to it that are still generating errors. It works for me.

Comment: my answer is focussed to help people with similar problem. If you vote -1, at least, explain why. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I remember now and yes, the problem is ARC. But you can exclude files from being complied under ARC by setting the following compiler flag in Build Phases >> Compile Sources:  -fno-objc-arc. If you select all the ASIHTTPRequest files and double-click, you can set the flag for all of them in one fell swoop.

ORIGINAL POST:

I've been using ASIHTTPRequest for a couple of weeks now and I remember reading a post somewhere about problems with Reachability, I just can't remember what it was exactly.

Anyway, this is what those lines in my Reachability.m look like:

```
//Start listening for reachability notifications on the current run loop
static void ReachabilityCallback(SCNetworkReachabilityRef target, SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags, void* info) {

#pragma unused (target, flags)
NSCAssert(info, @"info was NULL in ReachabilityCallback");
NSCAssert([(NSObject*) info isKindOfClass: [Reachability class]], @"info was the wrong class in ReachabilityCallback");

//We're on the main RunLoop, so an NSAutoreleasePool is not necessary, but is added defensively
// in case someone uses the Reachablity object in a different thread.
NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];

// Post a notification to notify the client that the network reachability changed.
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: kReachabilityChangedNotification 
                                                    object: (Reachability *) info];

[pool release];

} // ReachabilityCallback()


- (BOOL) startNotifier {

    SCNetworkReachabilityContext    context = {0, self, NULL, NULL, NULL};

    if(SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback(reachabilityRef, ReachabilityCallback, &context)) {

        if(SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop(reachabilityRef, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode)) {

            return YES;

        }

    }

    return NO;

} // startNotifier
```

Comment: same code as I am using, working but not with iOS5. Problem came due to ARC.